# Why Checkbox with Indeterminate state is being changed to Unchecked state?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `CheckBoxList`s: `primaryAntennas` and `secondaryAntennas`
When you check primary antenna with index X, secondary antenna with index X should be disabled (i.e, I check primary antenna #1, secondary antenna #1 is disabled). Reverse, should be work same way. Disabled by setting the checkbox to `CheckState.Indeterminate`

[image: example1]
I quickly found out, that you can click on `Indeterminate` checkbox, and it's state will be set to `CheckState.Unchecked`.
[image: example2]
To counter that, I added a check to the click handler, which resets the checkbox back to indeterminate state:

```
if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
{
   this.primaryAntennas.ItemCheck -= this.primaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
   // set it back to indeterminate state 
   this.primaryAntennas.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
   this.primaryAntennas.ItemCheck += this.primaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
   return;
}
```

Still, after the click handler finishes, checkbox is unchecked.
Here a complete code for the click handler:
(You might notice that I explicitly unassigned event handlers, since calling itself can create an infinite loop. Additionally, event-handlers can call each other, creating another possibility of infinite loops)

```
private void primaryAntennas_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    //check if checkbox is indeterminate
    if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
    {
        this.primaryAntennas.ItemCheck -= this.primaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
        // set it back to indeterminate state 
        this.primaryAntennas.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        this.primaryAntennas.ItemCheck += this.primaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
        return;
    }

    // if the item was checked
    // disable the secondary antenna with the same index
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        // disable the secondary antenna
        this.secondaryAntennas.ItemCheck -= this.secondaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
        secondaryAntennas.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        this.secondaryAntennas.ItemCheck += this.secondaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
        return;
    }
    // if the item was unchecked
    // disable the primary antenna with the same index
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        // check to make sure it does not belong to other portal
        if (_myConfig.secondaryAntessasUsed[e.Index] == -1)
        {
            // disable even
            this.secondaryAntennas.ItemCheck -= this.secondaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
            // uncheck the antenna
            secondaryAntennas.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Unchecked);
            this.secondaryAntennas.ItemCheck += this.secondaryAntennas_ItemCheck;
            return;
        }
    } 
}// end of primaryAntennas_ItemCheck()
```

Comment: should't be trying to find the `CheckBoxList` selected item and that being said you could do that so much easier using a foreach loop for example `foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items){ }` you could even disable the other one based on the first onces checked the assign the other one based on it's index position to  CheckState.Checked or  CheckState.UnChecked

Comment: Is it allowed that the user select multiple primary and multiple secondary antennas, and that you just don't allow a single antenna to be used for both? i.e. Primary = 1 & 2, Secondary = 3 & 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pretty novel way to fake a "disabled" state for a checkbox.  Not so sure you'll do your user a favor with it, much easier to just make it exclusive, checking one unchecks the other.   It is technically possible however, just force the e.NewValue state so the click doesn't have any effect.

Give both CheckedListBoxes the same event handler:

```
    private bool updatingChecks;

    private void checkedListBoxes_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (updatingChecks) return;
        updatingChecks = true;
        var otherBox = sender == checkedListBox1 ? checkedListBox2 : checkedListBox1;
        if (otherBox.GetItemCheckState(e.Index) == CheckState.Checked) e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) otherBox.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked) otherBox.SetItemChecked(e.Index, false);
        updatingChecks = false;
    }
```

The version that makes more sense to me, it doesn't ignore the user's click:

```
    private void checkedListBoxes_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        var otherBox = sender == checkedListBox1 ? checkedListBox2 : checkedListBox1;
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) otherBox.SetItemChecked(e.Index, false);
    }
```

Do make sure that you didn't actually meant to implement RadioButtons.  Sure looks like it.

Comment: +1: _make sure that you didn't actually meant to implement_ RadioButtons - so true. __No__ user can understand a 3rd state checkbox. I have a hard time when I meet one.

Comment: +1: I had the same answer more or less, but yours is much more concise. Especially the second one.

Comment: Hans, thank you for the detailed response. Right now, I am trying to rewrite my code to look more or less like your code and see if it will work. 
Did you mean `var otherBox = sender == checkedListBox1 ? checkedListBox2 : checkedListBox2;` (you have : `checkedListBox1;`)

Comment: No, that code was correct.  The event handler is suitable for *both* CheckListBoxes.  Rename the variables, you'll want primaryAttennas instead of checkListBox1, secondaryAttennas instead of checkListBox2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SetItemCheckState` from inside the event handler will not work. Instead you need to set the `NewValue` property on the event args.

```
if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
{
   e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
   return;
}
```

This additionally fixes your recursion issue, because it works inside the existing event instead of triggering new ones.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would enforce user from unchecking listbox option

```
private void checkedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate && e.NewValue !=  CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            checkedListBox.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to use the ItemChecked event for each checkbox to set the value of the other checkbox items. In order to make this work, we need to keep track of whether or not the ItemChecked event was triggered by the user clicking on a box, or by our code from the other ItemChecked event.

Also, since the code would be nearly identical in both ItemCheck events, I created a separate method for it, which takes in the 'other' checkbox (the one to change) along with the event args.

Here's how I would do it:

```
private bool userTriggered = true; // True means the user is triggering the event

private void primaryAntennas_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // If triggered by other ItemCheck method, let the change take place...
    if (!userTriggered) return;

    // Otherwise we process it and update the other CheckedListBox
    processItemCheckEvent(this.secondaryAntennas, e);
}

private void secondaryAntennas_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // If triggered by other ItemCheck method, let the change take place...
    if (!userTriggered) return;

    // Otherwise we process it and update the other CheckedListBox
    processItemCheckEvent(this.primaryAntennas, e);
}

private void processItemCheckEvent(CheckedListBox otherCheckedListBox, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore user changes if we're 'disabled'
    if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Indeterminate)
    {
        e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
    }
    // Otherwise change the other check box
    else
    {
        // Now we're manipulating the other checkedListBox, 
        // so set userTriggered to false
        userTriggered = false;
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            otherCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
        }
        else
        {
            otherCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, CheckState.Unchecked);
        }
        // And set it back again now
        userTriggered = true;
    }
}
```